# Htaccess Forwarding: How To Redirect Everything But Root Page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi there quick question (regarding htaccess): I want to be able to have my website go down for maintenance easily.

I want *everything* to be forwarded to /maintenance/index.html *except* the root / home page. I tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$ [NC] #Dont forward the root!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance/index.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /maintenance/index.html [R=302,L]
```

However it didn't work. Going to my website example.com still forwarded to the maintenance page. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I figure it must be the "!^$" or something.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance/index\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ /maintenance/index.html [R=302,L]
```

`.+` will make sure that root page is not redirected.

Also make sure this rule is first rule.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked great!